# Separate a project from Xcode Workspace

Tags: xcode

I have added two project in my Xcode workspace and both of these projects share a lot of classes and artwork. 
Now i want to separate my later project from the workspace or not separate but i want all the classes in the later project's folder too but couldn't see them when i open the project folder directly.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the project that should be separate. Choose File > Add Files to ProjectName. Locate the shared files in the Open Panel. Select the Copy items into destination group's folder checkbox to have the shared files copied to the project's folder.

[image]